# how to access remote computer windows service using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, windows-services

how to access remote computer windows service using asp.net

Comment: Unless the windows service is listening on a remote port with some sort of SNMP trap, you will need to stop the service using the remote machine's local commands. This means having a web service (or similar) running on the remote machine to handle the request. If this is the case, then @Aristos is probably the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way is to open a dos command from inside asp.net and call [the **net** command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736564(WS.10).aspx),
for example starting the service by call "**net start ServiceName**"

### Code

[How to run interactive command shell or bath files from asp.net](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Interactive_Command_Shell.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your response :-) . But my requirement is to start and stop remote computer's windows service using asp.net coding.

Comment: @user548593 I add one more answer

Answer (score 0):

On other way that I find (but not test) is to use the [ServiceController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx).

```
public static void StartService(string serviceName, int timeoutMilliseconds)
{
  ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName);
  try
  {
    TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds);

    service.Start();
    service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeout);
  }
  catch
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Reference: http://www.csharp-examples.net/restart-windows-service/